# Yelp dataset: Json to csv converter (python 3)

Tags: python, json, csv, python-3.6, yelp

So, I'm trying to work with the Yelp dataset. I'm using python 3!
I've found a code to convert a json file to a csv and I've opened cmd on Windows and typed:
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python.exe json_to_csv_converter.py review.json

The command gives me no more errors but it actually didn't convert (there is no csv file as output).

**Can you please help me understand why it's not working?**

The code inside the converter.py is:

```
import argparse
import collections
import csv
import json


def read_and_write_file(json_file_path, csv_file_path, column_names):
    with open(csv_file_path, 'w+') as fout:
        csv_file = csv.writer(fout)
    csv_file.writerow(list(column_names))
    with open(json_file_path, encoding="utf8") as fin:

        for line in fin:
            line_contents = json.loads(line)
            csv_file.writerow(get_row(line_contents, column_names))


def get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(json_file_path):
    column_names = set()
    with open(json_file_path) as fin:

        for line in fin:
            line_contents = json.loads(line)
        column_names.update(
            set(get_column_names(line_contents).keys())
            )
        return column_names


def get_column_names(line_contents, parent_key=''):
    column_names = []
    for k, v in line_contents.items():
        column_name = "{0}.{1}".format(parent_key, k) if parent_key else k
    if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
        column_names.extend(
                get_column_names(v, column_name).items()
                )
    else:
        column_names.append((column_name, v))
    return dict(column_names)


def get_nested_value(d, key):

    if '.' not in key:
        if key not in d:
            return None
    return d[key]
    base_key, sub_key = key.split('.', 1)
    if base_key not in d:
        return None
    sub_dict = d[base_key]
    return get_nested_value(sub_dict, sub_key)


def get_row(line_contents, column_names):
    row = []
    for column_name in column_names:
        line_value = get_nested_value(
            line_contents,
            column_name,
            )
    if isinstance(line_value, str):
        row.append('{0}'.format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))
    elif line_value is not None:
        row.append('{0}'.format(line_value))
    else:
        row.append('')
    return row

    if name == 'main':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Convert Yelp data from JSON format to CSV.',
        )

        parser.add_argument(
            'json_file',
            type=str,
            help='The json file to convert.',
            )

        args = parser.parse_args()

        json_file = args.json_file
        csv_file = '{0}.csv'.format(json_file.split('.json')[0])

        column_names = get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(json_file)
        read_and_write_file(json_file, csv_file, column_names)
```

It might be a silly question (sorry I'm not used to python), but do I need to input the json path, json file name, csv path, csv file name, etc? If so, what is the appropriate way of doing it?

Thank you so much.

Carmem

Comment: Give us a *minimal* and *working* code example, with example data and the errors you have.

Comment: @buhtz, the dataset is: https://www.yelp.com/dataset. I don't have examples because I haven't been able to open the file yet (that's why I'm trying the code). But there are no errors. It runs, but nothing happens (there is no output file)...So I come to this question: Do I need to input the json path, json file name, csv path, csv file name, etc? If so, what is the appropriate way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with your code is the following line

```
if name == 'main':
```

i think it was

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

so, here is the code that might work.

```
import argparse
import collections
import csv
import json


def read_and_write_file(json_file_path, csv_file_path, column_names):
    with open(csv_file_path, 'w+') as fout:
        csv_file = csv.writer(fout)
    csv_file.writerow(list(column_names))
    with open(json_file_path, encoding="utf8") as fin:

        for line in fin:
            line_contents = json.loads(line)
            csv_file.writerow(get_row(line_contents, column_names))


def get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(json_file_path):
    column_names = set()
    with open(json_file_path) as fin:

        for line in fin:
            line_contents = json.loads(line)
        column_names.update(
            set(get_column_names(line_contents).keys())
            )
        return column_names


def get_column_names(line_contents, parent_key=''):
    column_names = []
    for k, v in line_contents.items():
        column_name = "{0}.{1}".format(parent_key, k) if parent_key else k
    if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
        column_names.extend(
                get_column_names(v, column_name).items()
                )
    else:
        column_names.append((column_name, v))
    return dict(column_names)


def get_nested_value(d, key):

    if '.' not in key:
        if key not in d:
            return None
    return d[key]
    base_key, sub_key = key.split('.', 1)
    if base_key not in d:
        return None
    sub_dict = d[base_key]
    return get_nested_value(sub_dict, sub_key)


def get_row(line_contents, column_names):
    row = []
    for column_name in column_names:
        line_value = get_nested_value(
            line_contents,
            column_name,
            )
    if isinstance(line_value, str):
        row.append('{0}'.format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))
    elif line_value is not None:
        row.append('{0}'.format(line_value))
    else:
        row.append('')
    return row

if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Convert Yelp data from JSON format to CSV.',
        )

        parser.add_argument(
            'json_file',
            type=str,
            help='The json file to convert.',
            )

        args = parser.parse_args()

        json_file = args.json_file
        csv_file = '{0}.csv'.format(json_file.split('.json')[0])

        column_names = get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(json_file)
        read_and_write_file(json_file, csv_file, column_names)
```

Comment: You're right. The code now works. However, it doesn't do anything (as in, there is no csv file as an output). Should I replace the "json_file_path", "json_file", "csv_file_path" and "csv_file" with paths and names of the file?

I know it's a very basic question, but I'm not familiar with it.

Thank you so much for your help!!!